# Bracha on Chia Seed Infused Water?

Tags: blessing, shehakol-beracha

Would this be shehakol or boreh pri since the [chia seeds are visible in the water](https://ohsheglows.com/2013/03/01/chia-fresca-a-natural-energy-drink/) even though they are very small? Would the concentration of chia seeds in the water matter?

For those unfamiliar:

[image]

Comment: Closely related : https://itorah.com/daily-halacha/lecture/the-beracha-for-coconut-milk-and-fruit-juices/776

Comment: I’d imagine this is a classic question of one food being subordinate to another food; you’re putting the chia seeds in to make the water better, but you’re not drinking the water to enhance the chia seeds.

Comment: This picture doesn't help me much. What is this and how is this made? VTC as Unclear

Comment: Offhand, this looks like a glass of water with chia seeds in it. It seems that the *ikar* is the water, and I assume you would be drinking it for the sake of the water and not the seeds. I.e., the seeds seem to be a "flavoring". Similar to making a glass of cucumber water. The purpose is drinking the water. I've never had this chia drink, so, you may want to explain the real purpose of this "cocktail". But, if my assumption is correct, seems pretty definite that this is still *shehakol*.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's an Aztec drink called iskiate. It's made with honey, chia, and lime in water.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring from [this article](https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/7-Fruit-Juice--Wine.html) that the bracha is *shehakol*. Here's why:

Even if this drink were to be considered "chia juice" the bracha would still be *shehakol*, as this is the common halachic rule on all fruit juices except for olive oil and wine. In this case, I doubt this is chia juice.

I doubt that the chia seeds impart any flavor to the water. Thus, this would be in the similar ruling as over-diluted wine which would make it *shehakol*.

Not mentioned in the article is the concept of *ikar* and *tafel* (main and subordinate.) It seems clear that the *ikar* here is the water and you are drinking this for the sake of the water, not for the seeds which are just adding a bit of flavor (if, in fact, it does.) Thus, again, *shekol*. However, if you were to chew the seeds, separately, you may have to make two brachot - one for the water and one for the seeds, as you are deliberately gaining benefit from the seeds.